# Provide JSON response and download file simultaneously with Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Requirement:** 
I need to create a Rest API which can allows to download a file as well as a JSON response.

I already have 2 different APIs to solve the purpose, but now I need to merge these APIs to a single one.

```
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFile1(
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = DEFAULT_FILE_NAME) String fileName) throws IOException {


    MediaType mediaType = MediaTypeUtils.getMediaTypeForFileName(this.servletContext, fileName);
    System.out.println("fileName: " + fileName);
    System.out.println("mediaType: " + mediaType);

    File file = new File(DIRECTORY + "/" + fileName);
    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            // Content-Disposition
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + file.getName())
            // Content-Type
            .contentType(mediaType)
            // Contet-Length
            .contentLength(file.length()) //
            .body(resource);
}
```

Above is the existing code that only return a file to download but I need a json response as well.

Answer (score 8):

You need to return Multipart content. See for example

https://github.com/juazugas/spring-boot-multipart/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/server/MultiEndpoint.java

The code

```
@GET
@Produces("multipart/mixed")
public MultipartBody getMulti2(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
    List<Attachment> attachments = new LinkedList<>();
    attachments.add(new Attachment("root", "application/json", service.getEntity(name)));
    attachments.add(new Attachment("image", "application/octet-stream", service.getEntityData(name)));
    return new MultipartBody(attachments, true);
}
```

Comment: I am getting multipart is Null, no adapter to handle null for apache multipart whenever I use produces="multipart/mixed", If I don't use this, then I get a Json of Object1 and Object2. Object1 contains the json I want but object2 should have been a file that shud be downloaded. Any Solutions?